# With PHP, how would I be able to load a anchored section in my content template, id based read from the filename?

Tags: php, include-path

So here is my layout:

```
    randompagenumber.php
             |
             |
           / | header.php
php include -| content.php
           \ | footer.php
```

The footer has a php script which calls the filename of the randompagenumer.php, removes it's extension and the dashes in it's name and outputs that number of the filename as a pagenumber in a bottom corner.
(left or right, depending if that number is even or odd).

I have a couple of pages (10 for now), I called them --1.php, --2.php, --3.php, --4.php, --5.php, --6.php, --7.php, --8.php, --9.php, -10.php, ...

So the script turns them simply in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ...

The code I have for the footer:

```
<?php
$pagenr = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$pagenr = str_replace( array( '.php', '.htm', '.html', '-', '_' ), '', $pagenr ); // Remove extensions and spaces in filename

if ($pagenr % 2 == 0) {
$footlr = "footerlinks";
$pcontainer = "pcontainerl";
} else{
$footlr = "footerrechts";
$pcontainer = "pcontainerr";
}
?>

<div id="<?=$footlr?>">
<div id="pnummer" class="pcontainer"><?=$pagenr?></div>
```

So the div with the id "*`<?=$footlr?>`*" would change name upon the verification of an even or odd number and by so would read another css style ( #footerlinks and #footerrechts ).

Now what I tried to accomplish has to do with content.php
I know from html that it is possible to link to anchors within it's own file and so I tried to have s somewhat same result with php but I only got to manage it for the php page to load, but it outputs the whole content.php

So basicly I would like to achieve that if the randompagenumber.php reads its filename (through footer.php), it loads the content from a certain section with id that is corresponding to that page number.

This is how I my randompagenumber.php looks like at the moment:

```
<?php    
$PageName = str_replace( array( $PageName ),  '#p', $pagenr, $PageName );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php include('templates/pheaderhst.php'); ?>
<?php include("templates/content.php$PageName"); ?>
<?php include('templates/pfooter.php'); ?>
```

So what I have done here, is making a new string named PageName which is calling the pagenr string  that is calculated from the footer.php and let it echo as the php page to load `<?php include("templates/content.php$PageName"); ?>`

Just to discover it is actually loading the whole page and not only the content of what I named the section id's.

So knowing that the php script changes a filename from 006.php to simply the number 6, then changes the 6 into #p6 (because an id can't start with a number, I named then with a p first).. How come it loads the full page and not just the content of my `<section id="p6">content of page 6</section>`?

For those interested, here is how content.php looks like;

```
<?php
?>
<section id="p1">
<div id="contentwrapperpaginas"><?php echo 'Content from page 1' ?></div>
</section>
<section id="p2">
<div id="contentwrapperpaginas"><?php echo 'Content from page 2' ?></div>
</section>
<section id="p3">
<div id="contentwrapperpaginas"><?php echo 'Content from page 3' ?></div>
</section>
<section id="p4">
<div id="contentwrapperpaginas"><?php echo 'Content from page 4' ?></div>
</section>
<section id="p5">
<div id="contentwrapperpaginas"><?php echo 'Content from page 5' ?></div>
</section>
<section id="p6">
<div id="contentwrapperpaginas"><?php echo 'Content from page 6' ?></div>
</section>
```

Comment: It will always load the full page, an anchor is used to 'jump' on the section you specified

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, @RomainB. would there be a way to only list the desired anchored item on a page load, after calculating the randompagenumber.php number?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE with solution**

So I got it to work!

First my content.php:

```
<?php
?>
...some div's with page id's here...
<div id="p5">
<div id="contentwrapperpaginas">Content from page 5</div>
</div>
<div id="p6">
<div id="contentwrapperpaginas"><p style="color:yellow;margin-left:-25px;">Content from page 6</p></div>
</div>
...some more div's with page id's here...
```

So with the following script I got it to manage to load only one single div and it's elements inside. The example used in my copy/paste will be loading the `<div id="p6">`. The script is inside index.php and loaded with `<?php echo $content_div[0]; ?>`.  :

```
$url = 'templates/content.php';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<div id="p6">' , $content );
$content_div = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );
```

The solution was changing the `<?php include("templates/content.php$pagenr"); ?>` to `<?php echo $content_div[0]; ?>`